# Mega Menu Tabs become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to replicate the "tabs" section as explained in this tutorial:[Google Material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html?optionsRadios=option2) Everthing works fine except when I insert a date which uses a datepicker widget from this url [DatePicker](http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/) As soon as I select the date from Dropdown 2 all the tabs in Megamenu become unresponsive as shown in this jsfiddle link

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/z24zu9h2/6/)

HTML code for the tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#remindertab" data-toggle="tab">Reminder</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="bootstrap-elements.html" data-target="#">
             Reports <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#dropdown1" data-toggle="tab">Insurance History Between Dates</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#dropdown2" data-toggle="tab">Insurance history of Account</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#dropdown3" data-toggle="tab">Insurance Amount between dates</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Bulletin Board</a></li>

    <p class="user" data-toggle="tab">Welcome Wasim(1117004017)</p>
```

Comment: It's the fault of the DatePicker plugin. On line 723, it calls `$(document).unbind('click')`, which stops bootstrap's propagation of the menu. I'd suggest finding a different datepicker that's coded well.

Comment: @Chad Thanks a lot ...Commenting that line of Code makes menu responsive again.

Comment: correct, but it will then rebind it every time that you open the datepicker... just not clean code is all.